# Not able to enable mod_deflate on Apache / CentOS7

Tags: apache, gzip, mod-deflate, apache-modules

I followed a simple tutorial from a good source, and gzip compression does not work.

1) I run the following to see whether mod_deflate is already installed:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep deflate
```

I got deflate_module (shared), so it was there.

2) I created a new file /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_deflate.conf with the following contents:

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|html|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesMatch>
```

I saved it and I run systemctl reload httpd.service. It did not work so I run systemctl restart httpd.service. Gzip compression still didn't work.

I checked the syntax of Apache config files with apachectl -t, and everything seems ok to. It still does not work.

What could be the reason of this? What would I check?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you check if compression is working or not? Have you checked the error log for any error messages?

Comment: How did you verify it's not working? Did you make a typo in your conf file and then `apachectl -t` to verify the conf file is even loaded? Why are you not just using CentOS packages for this which work fine?

Comment: I checked with two online tools http://CheckGzipCompression.com and http://WhatsMyIp.org/http-compression-test. I did not look into the logs yet, and there could be some info there. I checked for spelling mistakes, and everything's correct.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes - It looks like the configuration file for this is loaded. When I made a typo and restarted the server it did not start. I corrected it, and everything works correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

I added this line only, and it works:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
```